# Issue with static cc on Google's MailApp Script

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

Okay, so I'm working on a script that will basically pull information from a spreadsheet to then send out in an email once an email address is added into the spreadsheet. The issue is I'm trying to add a noReply and cc setting but it seems to then break my script to where it keeps sending emails or doesn't send any at all.

Theory: I think 'cc' is throwing the issue as the script is reading it as a recipient and just sending the email out instead of using the recipient that's added into the spreadsheet. This is the reference I'm following: https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/mail/mail-app#sendEmail(String,String,String,Object)

This is my code with the issue section being commented as such:

```js
// This constant is written in column M for rows for which an email
// has been sent successfully.
var EMAIL_SENT = 'EMAIL_SENT';


/**
 * Sends non-duplicate emails with data from the current spreadsheet.
 */
function sendEmails2() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var startRow = 2; // First row of data to process
  var numRows = 3; // Number of rows to process
  // Fetch the range of cells
  var dataRange = sheet.getRange(startRow, 1, numRows, 20);
  // Fetch values for each row in the Range.
  var data = dataRange.getValues();
  for (var i = 0; i < data.length; ++i) {
    var row = data[i];
    var emailAddress = row[8]; // Column I
    var message = ('For the ticket below, please ensure that you call the user as the first resort before following up via email.' + '\n\n TimeStamp: ' + row[1] + '\n Agent Name: ' + row[2] + '\n Your site: ' + row[3] + '\n Zendesk Link: ' + row[4] + '\n Summary of User Issue: ' + row[5] + '\n De-Escalation Attempted:' + row[6] + '\n User Contact Number ' + row[7]); // Fetch of columns B-H
    var emailSent = row[12]; // Column M
    if (emailSent !== EMAIL_SENT) { // Prevents sending duplicates and everything after && emailAddress is just testing a fix but didn't work
      var subject = 'You have been assigned a Supervisor Call. Please Action Within 24 hours!';
      MailApp.sendEmail(emailAddress, subject, message, { // Section below gives the issue
        noReply: true,
        cc: 'cc@email.com'
      });
      sheet.getRange(startRow + i, 13).setValue(EMAIL_SENT);
      // Make sure the cell is updated right away in case the script is interrupted
      SpreadsheetApp.flush();
    }
  }
}
```

Screenshot of spreadsheet layout:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4RCIm.png)

This is my first time writing out a question on Stack but feel free to ask and I can detail more of what you need in order to help out.

Comment: I dont see the advanced parameter for priority in the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/mail/mail-app#sendEmail(String,String,String,Object))  I believe it's expecting `a comma-separated list of email addresses `

Comment: Hey @Cooper ignore the priority piece for now. I forgot I even had it in there, so my fault. 

The main thing is how can I get noReply and CC to work? As mentioned, the second I add in that section the if statement for duplicates stops working and the behavior just gets all wonky.

Comment: noReply is a boolean not a string

Comment: Correct @Cooper hence mine being set as a boolean. What about CC? I know it's a comma separated list, but passing it breaks my script.

Do you have a better way for me to pass cc within my if statement?

Comment: In your question noReply is a string

Comment: Fair enough @Cooper I fixed the noReply, but now it sends out 3 emails at once even if the columns in the spreadsheet are empty.

Can you see anything else that looks incorrect maybe? I edited the code in the question for you as well :)

Comment: I guess you will just have to single step through the script and figure out what's not working

Comment: This is most likely not the problem but I would write this `if (emailSent !== EMAIL_SENT)` like this `if (emailSent != EMAIL_SENT)`

Comment: Thanks for the help @Cooper I can continue debugging and see what I can find out with it. Appreciate the look.

Comment: Have you been able to solve the issue with cooper's help? If not can you update the question with new details or clarifying you current situation?

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get this working with Cooper's help. I had to do some small formatting changes to get it working but ultimately the code wasn't incorrect, just format issues that caused it to not be read appropriately.

Appreciate the help!